# python jwt_required decorator with headers

Tags: python, http, request, jwt, decorator

I am trying to make a custom JWT_required decorator that passes the request.headers. So far everything I have tried gives me the following error:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
>   needed an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing
>   for information about how to avoid this problem.

Here is my decorator:

```
def jwt_required(headers):
def jwt_req(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def function_that_runs_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print(headers)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return function_that_runs_func
return jwt_req
```

and here is how I am trying to utilize the decorator:

```
class Cert(Resource):
@jwt_required(request.headers)
def get(self):
```

I understand what the error is saying; however, I am not sure on how to get around it. I was hoping to make a copied dictionary to pass to the jwt decorator but that did not work as well.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding @jwt_required(request) and then finding the headers in the decorator by request.headers